# Why filtering objects which has undefined key gives error in TypeScript strict mode

Tags: typescript, strict-mode

I have this piece of code written in TypeScript with strict mode enabled.

```js
const arr: ({ name?: string })[] = [
    { name: 'foo' },
    {},
    { name: 'bar' }
]

function select(): string[] {
    return arr
        .filter(e => e.name !== undefined)
        .map(e => e.name)
}
```

It fails to compile with this error:

```
Type '(string | undefined)[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
  Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
    Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Why is that? Aren't all objects with property `name` is `undefined` filtered out before being `map`ped? If I change the return type of the `select` function to `(string | undefined)[]`, it compiles successfully.

Comment: I am not sure why is that but, if you need a fix: `function select(): string[] {return arr.filter(e => e.name !== undefined).map(e => e.name) as string[]
}`. I add `as string[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You filtered an array but that `filter` itself does not change returning type so that's why `filter(e => e.name !== undefined)` returns `(string | undefined)[]`.
You should "cast" `e.name` to string to turn `(string | undefined)` into `string`:

```
.map(e => e.name as string)
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a proposal on this or are they not planning to change it? I think an extra type-cast is pretty unnecessary here.

Comment: Dunno. Only time will tell )